# Video is opening with a reduced screen size in KM Player

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, kmplayer

Yesterday while watching a video I accidentally pressed a random button of the keypad. From then any video is opening with reduced frame size.

[image]

Each time I have to zoom in to watch the video. **How do I solve this problem?**

I have tried Screen Control >> Keep Video Frame to >> Window size (or 100%). But it's also not working.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I quite possible that you pressed inadvertently <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>. Try pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>. Or right-click, select Video (Advanced) -> Resize, then select Always. Then close and restart KM Player.

[image: IMG:]

Comment: Maybe. I have already used "Initialize All Presets". (Got help through Facebook) . Now the problem is gone. Thanks. Your information will be helpful later.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that helped me was to go to Screen Controls-->Keep Video Frame to-->One and a half size(150 %).

Maybe it depends on the display settings on Windows(which in my case the scale is 150 %) and not letting your cats run through your keyboard.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).